# Azure Function Cron Expression on 3rd weekday of the month

Tags: azure, cron, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

Is there any relevant CRON expression to trigger the azure function on the 3rd weekday of the month on specific months .I tried the cron expression "0 0 22 3W 2,5,8,11 ?"..The CRON expression indicates " At 22:00:00pm, on the nearest weekday to the 3rd of the month, in February, May, August and November" . It should be 3rd day of the respective months. If the 3rd day falls on a weekend(Saturday or Sunday) then the function on nearest weekday .But i am getting the below error When running it in Azure

"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'RefundProcessForAppliedForTimerTriggerFunction'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions: The schedule expression '0 0 22 3W 2,5,8,11 ?' was not recognized as a valid cron expression or timespan string."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the main documentation to the cron expressions for timer triggers: 
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp#ncrontab-expressions

I believe you want something like this:
'0 0 22 * 2,5,8,11 3'

I read this as , 22 hour on the 2,5,8,11 month and 3rd day of the week.(day of the week going 0-6, believe 0 being sunday

If i'm misunderstanding and you just want the first weekday the 3rd day of the week of the month(just once a month on the third weekday)

Then you want this:
I believe you want something like this:
'0 0 22 1-7 2,5,8,11 3'

Specific examples here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp#ncrontab-examples

Comment: It should be 3rd day of the respective months. If the 3rd day falls on a weekend(Saturday or Sunday)  then the function on nearest weekday.

Comment: I don't believe what you want is possible in ncrontab, looking at the unit tests on github and online ncrontab testers:

https://github.com/atifaziz/NCrontab/blob/master/NCrontab.Tests/CrontabScheduleTests.cs





The document for timer trigger links to ncrontab but sadly i don't see any examples of that behavior.

https://ncrontab.swimburger.net/